# "Leadscrew" block in Simscape: is it possibile to convert this block to rotating nut and translating screw? How the physics is modeled by the block?

Tags: matlab, physics, simulink, modeling, simscape

I have to model a physical system that uses a ballscrew to convert the motion of the rotating nut in the traslation motion of the screw.
I'm using the block Leadscrew, but the results are not good and I'd like to know more on the block:

- which equations are introduced by the block?
- how the block calculates F_loss with given efficiencies?
- can I change (and how can I) the block to have actually a rotating nut and a translating screw?
- how the forces and torques are calculated?
- are there any other blocks that better model the problem I have?

I tried search online but i didn't find any help at all